# How to make server connection in separate file and use other files as a function in main server file using node Js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am making node.js application using mongo db for database.
i am creating server in all files and it is running fine. But when i run the whole project, it is creating server every time when function is called. Can anyone guide me how to create server and database connection in one file and call other Api's as a function? I have tried this but this is not working. 
when i call function follower from followers api file, it doesn't go inside the function and is not printing console. Plz help me

server.js

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var resultant;
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var qs = require('querystring');
var common = require('./followersapi');
```

var db = require('./dbconnection');

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) 
  {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});

  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:9001/');

 common.follower();
 db.connectToServer();
  }).listen(9080);
```

dbconnection.js

```
var MongoClient = require( 'mongodb' ).MongoClient;

var _db;

module.exports = {

  connectToServer: function( callback ) {
    MongoClient.connect( "mongodb://localhost:27017/background_wallpapers", function( err, db ) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("We are connected");
        }
        else 
       console.log("We are not connected");
      _db = db;
      return callback( err );
    } );

  },

  getDb: function() {
    return _db;
  }
};
```

followersapi.js

```
module.exports = {

  follower: function () {
console.log("hello");
}

};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, when you say not working, what error you are getting? Please add error logs, it will help SO member to understand your problem better and provide you with solution.

Comment: Thankyou dkb.. ok i will update my question

Comment: the mongodb initialization file is never called. I also tried your code and it's printing to console. I believe you might be confused but the createServer function is taking a function that is supposed to handle all upcoming requests. the function given isn't really an "on init" function for the server but a handler for all requests

Comment: omarwaleed no it is not printing console inside function follower

Comment: you shouldn't connect to server on each request. call the connection function before http.createServer

Comment: thankyou omarwaleed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kindly test this use db.connection before createServer

```
        var db = require('./dbconnection');
        db.connectToServer();
        http.createServer(function (req, res) 
          {
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});

            console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:9001/');

        common.follower();
         }).listen(9080);
```

Comment: thankyou now it is connecting with db_connection. But why it doesn't go inside follower function?

Comment: kindly tick the answer :D

Comment: Atiq Ur Rehman can you please guide me more. i didn't get your point

Comment: Try to debug it must be go inside that function.. are you seen the logs server running...?

Comment: How to send post and get request to another file ini node js?

Comment: you must create the route file first

Comment: i can send you my code file... just check and then let me know you got it

Comment: are you using express.js ?